# Checksum of a loop device file exactly reproducible?

Tags: linux, loops, timestamp, checksum, mount

how can I mount and unmount a file as loop device and have exactly the **same MD5 checksum** afterwards? (Linux)

Here's the workflow:

1. I take a fresh copy of a **fixed template** file which contains a prepared
   **ext2** root file system.
2. The file is mounted with `mount -t ext2 <file> <mountpoint> -o loop,sync,noatime,nodiratime`
3. ( Here, some files will be added in future--but ignore this for a moment and focus on mount / umount )
4. `umount`
5. Take the MD5 sum of the file.
6. I expect the same, reproducible checksum every time I perform exactly the same steps.

However, when I repeat the process (remember: taking a *fresh* copy of the template file), I always get a different checksum.

I assume on the one hand that still some timestamps are set internally (I tried to avoid this with the `noatime` option) or, on the other hand, Linux manages the file system on its own way where I have no influence. That means: the files and timestamps inside might might be the same, but the way the file system is arranged inside the file might be differnt and therefore kind of random.

In comparison, when I create a **zip file** of a file tree, and I touched all files with a defined timestamp, the checksum of the zip file is reproducible.

Is there a way to keep the mount or file access that controlled as I need at all?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the file system on disk format. I believe ext2 keep sat the least the mount count counter - how many time the file system was mounted. I don't remember any mount option to tell it not to write that counter (and perhaps other data items) but you can:

a. mount the file system read only. Then the checksum will not change of course.

b. Change the ext2 file system kernel driver to add an option to not change the counter and possible other data bits.

The more interesting question is why you are interested is such an option. I think there is probably a better way to achieve what you are trying to do - whatever it is.

Comment: `tune2fs` can list and reset some of internal variables.

Comment: @Banthar that is true, but since he is trying to keep the same checksum, changing the checksum (using mount/umount) and then changing it back (using tune2fs) is not exactly the same thing as keeping the same checksum

Comment: Read-only is not useful when I add some files later. And hacking the kernel driver... I didn't intent to go that far... ;-). The idea is to have a file system for an embedded product. For regulatory reasons it's mandatory to prove the identity of every file. We do this with the single files we copy in, and it was handy when we could do that with the deployed file system as well.